# Solving a line integral - splitting up in int multiple "segments"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, line-integrals

I have the following formula:

$$f = \oint\frac{ds}{C}$$

This integral happens over a (closed) circle with radius $r$, so normally the solution would be:

$$\oint\frac{ds}{C} = \frac{2\pi r}{C}$$
However now I have a circle that has 2 different constants: between $0$ and $\theta$ radians $C$ is changed.

My questions are:

1. What is the exact solution
2. How to write the boundaries/integral correctly.

For 1. I think:
$$ \oint\frac{ds}{C_s} = \frac{r \theta}{C_0} + \frac{r (2\pi - \theta)}{C_1} $$

For the second I got as far as:
$$\oint\frac{ds}{C_s} = \int_0^{\theta}\frac{ds}{C_0} + \int_\theta^{2\pi}\frac{ds}{C_1}$$
However this is obviously wrong, as the radius just dropped from the equation. So how do I solve this line integral - properly?

---

A small image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what a circle with two different constants is. What does the problem ask exactly?

Comment: Well it's not a "asked" per se.. It's a problem I run into as part of a larger problem. But anyways I have a thin walled structure, with two different materials (and thus shear moduli) and thicknesses. And then I have to find the "optimal" $\theta$ to minimize the total mass while keeping the rest below a certain point. I do get it down to above formula where $C$ stands for the combination of $G \cdot t$. - I'll try to scan a drawing I made

Comment: GitGud: what he means is that he's trying to integrate a piece-wise constant function over the circle, and needs notation to express that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the integral notation, as you observe.

1. Your answer is fine.
2. For this case, it's probably better to say 
   $$
   \gamma_0: [0, \theta] \to \mathbb R^2 : t \mapsto (\cos(t), \sin(t)) \\
   \gamma_1: [\theta, 2\pi] \to \mathbb R^2 : t \mapsto (\cos(t), \sin(t)) 
   $$
   and then say that your left hand integral is

$$
\int_{\gamma_0} \frac{ds}{C_0} + \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{ds}{C_1}.
$$